# Javascript show times to next 15 minute intervals

Tags: javascript

I am displaying data and showing the times for a tasklist according to 15 minutes interval. actually want to show to the next 15, so that if the time now is 3.23 pm, I want the next time to show as 3.45pm not 3.38pm, then after 3.45 we would show 4.00pm

```
<%
var date = new Date();
for(var i=1 ;i<=4;i++)
  {

var d2 = new Date ( date );
d2.setMinutes ( date.getMinutes() + 15*i );

var hour = d2.getHours() % 12;
 var min = d2.getMinutes();
 var seprater=":";


 %>

    <th style='color: white; font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(28, 94, 85);'><%=hour+seprater+min%></th> 



    <%

 <!-- <th style='color: white; font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(28, 94, 85);'><%=hour+seprater+min+15%></th> 
      <th style='color: white; font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(28, 94, 85);'><%=hour+seprater+min+15%></th> 
      <th style='color: white; font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(28, 94, 85);'><%=hour+seprater+min+15%></th> 
       -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just copy the following codes inside "body" tag and open in browser to check**

```
<script>
var date = new Date();
var time = date.getTime();
var mint = date.getMinutes();

for(var i=1 ;i<=4;i++)
  {
var quarter_min = Math.ceil((mint/15))*15 +(i*15);
var d2 = new Date(time + (quarter_min-mint) *60000);
document.write((d2.getHours()%12)+":"+d2.getMinutes()+"<br />");
  }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your script ("<%"?), but you can do something like

```
var date = new Date();
for(var i=0 ;i<4;i++)
{
    var d2 = new Date ( date );

    if (i == 0) {
        d2.setMinutes ( date.getMinutes() );
    } else {
        d2.setMinutes ( Math.round(date.getMinutes()/15)*15 + 15*(i-1) );
    }
var hour = d2.getHours() % 12;
var min = d2.getMinutes();
var seprater=":";
```

But there are some more problems in your code, like leading zero, ...

Comment: you're right - code removing leading zero and this is not what is wanted